# while loop does not save array value

Tags: php

Why does my while loop not output the value of `$st['status']`?

The two files are being downloaded successfully.

`json_encode($st)` outputs nothing.

```
while (true) {
    clearstatcache();

    # Get filesize
    $fileSize = ftp_size($conn_id, $txt_filename);

    # Check if txt (status) file exist
    # Filesize will return -1 if no file exist
    if($fileSize == -1) {

        $st['status'] = 'no file';

        # no file
        return true; // continue loop until file exist

    }else{

        # File exist
        # Move remote files (xml and txt) to local folder

        # Download both txt and xml files                           
        if(
            ftp_get($conn_id, $localstatusfolder.'/'.$txt_filename, $txt_filename, FTP_BINARY) &&
            ftp_get($conn_id, $localstatusfolder.'/'.$xml_filename, $xml_filename, FTP_BINARY)
        ) {

            # Files downloaded to local folder
            $st['status'] = 'ok';

            ftp_close($conn_id);

            return false;

        }else{

            # Fejl, ftp_get
            $st['status'] = 'FTP003';

            ftp_close($conn_id);

            return false;
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($st);
```

Comment: what's your output if you use var_dump($st); ?

Comment: using `return` is the issue. Use `break` instead.

Comment: var_dump = nothing, no output. I receive page error 500 when replacing return with break.

Comment: You have a `while (true)` loop, but every branch inside has a `return`, so the loop only ever runs once. You also have a `return` statement with a comment indicating you probably meant `continue`. The loop as it is now is useless.

Comment: " I receive page error 500" In that case check what the real underlying error was. 500 is just a generic code for a server error. Switch on PHP error reporting, and/or check your logs if you have them. Now you're breaking out of the loop, perhaps something else is going wrong.

Comment: Using break and continue did the trick - works perfectly now :) Put up an  answer so I can accept it :) Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in these lines,

```
ftp_get($conn_id, $localstatusfolder.'/'.$txt_filename, $txt_filename, FTP_BINARY) &&
ftp_get($conn_id, $localstatusfolder.'/'.$xml_filename, $xml_filename, FTP_BINARY)
```

Try removing these lines and then check and yes remove, `return false` from your code, it means code won't run here after. Use `break` which is suitable in this case.